# How to change permissions in folders and files from "root" to "me" in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: permissions

Well I am trying to change permission of the background files in the folder in **/usr/share** and also the folder **/usr/share/gnome-background-properties** so I can have the all my wallpapers together. At the moment it says that I don't own the files and is owned by root.

I tried a couple of similar suggestions in other posts but they didn't work.

Comment: Can you please provide details of the suggestions you tried?

Comment: Well I tried this one http://askubuntu.com/questions/280728/change-permissions-on-all-folders-and-files

Comment: Why do you need to change ownership of those files ? If you're just using them to set your desktop background, you don't need to change anything.  Strongly suggest you stay away from anything root-owned.

Comment: Especially don't touch `/usr/share` at all, if you don't want to mess up your system

Comment: Oh OK, someone on another site said that I would have to change permissions on those to folders to put all the wallpapers in one folder and be able to just use the "appearance/look" app. .... I hear you about don't touch and I won't, not now.

Comment: @ShaneW if you want to use your own files in that folder, simply place those files into the folder.  I'll write an answer on how to do that. Are you ok with terminal ?

Comment: Yes I am learning it all :) so yes I can follow in the terminal.

Comment: I just cleared the pictures folder in Appearence and got the folder I wanted so all is good without any changed to the root files ... thank you so much for your help.