# Giving myself the folder and file permissions I need in Ubuntu 16.04 using Nautilus with recursive file / folder permissions

Tags: permissions, nautilus

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 and copied back all my backed up files. I used same method and user name.  But I must have done something wrong.  I [How to change permissions in folders and files from "root" to "me" in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851683/how-to-change-permissions-in-folders-and-files-from-root-to-me-in-ubuntu-16) but I struggle with command line and things like `chmod` so I prefer

```
gksudo nautilus
```

but I am having to set my permissions to allow me access instead of just root.  So I have to set permissions on every folder I want to access, every subfolder and every file in those folders.  Home folder is ok but when I want to work in

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs
```

for example it is very tedious and I am constantly finding other areas with the same problem. Alternatively I could set my privileges as root but that has security / safety issues I believe.  I really want to give myself selected entire folders including subfolders and all files contained using Nautilus GUI if possible.

Comment: I don't know the GUI but in the terminal  it would be one line `sudo chown -R <User> /path/to/folder` where the -R is for recursive. To tweak your question you should add this "recursive" keyword to the title..

Comment: Well this is a veeery old one but maybe it helps you having a look at [this post](https://blogs.gnome.org/cneumair/2005/12/26/nautilus-now-with-recursive-permission-changes/)

Comment: @derHugo actually that is the answer, you should post it right now until another one copy you

Comment: @derHugo - The link you gave mus be quite old the current Nautilus has a single button for changing permissions on subfolders and files but it simply does not work - only the parent folder is affected.  You have to change all subfolders and files individually.  So thanks for your assistance but I still not have an answer to'Giving myself the folder and file'  - also I have amended the question as you suggestedpermissions I need in Ubuntu 16.04 using Nautilus

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the GUI but in the terminal it would be one line `sudo chown -R <User> /path/to/folder` where the -R is for "recursive".

Anyway there is a possibility in nautilus ...well this is a veeery old one but maybe it helps you having a look at [this post](https://blogs.gnome.org/cneumair/2005/12/26/nautilus-now-with-recursive-permission-changes/)

Comment: Nautilus does have a button to change permissions for folders and files but it simply does nothing - also i cant even run nautilus as my normal user I have to load it from command line as gksudo nautilus - it seems I don't have control of my own computer any more

Comment: I may have to get my head around terminal after all - but would prefer Nautilus

Comment: "it seems I don't have control of my own computer any more" ... hmm than maybe you already played aournd to much with file permissions? Anyway you wont be able to change certain files' permissions without having root permissions so somehow it makes sence that nautilus can only be run with gksudo

Comment: Have not played around with any file permissions other than having to allow myself access to files i created in the first place on previous system

Comment: can anybody tell me why all files i copy will not allow me access and how i can change that please - i just want access to my own files